# React Components are not refreshing when the prop data is changed

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
import './App.css';
import { MenuItem, FormControl, Select, Card, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import Infobox from './Infobox';
import Map from './Map';
import Table from './Table';
import { sortData } from './util';
import LineGraph from './LineGraph';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("WorldWide");
  const [countryInfo, setCountryInfo] = useState({});
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState("cases");
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([-34, -64]);
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all").then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      setCountryInfo(data)
    })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountriesData = async () => {
      await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries").then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        const countries = data.map(country => ({
          name: country.country,
          value: country.countryInfo.iso2
        }));

        const sortedData = sortData(data);
        setTableData(sortedData);
        setCountries(countries);
      });
    };
    getCountriesData();
  }, []);

  const onCountryChange = async (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value;

    const url = countryCode === "WorldWide" ? "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all" : `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${countryCode}`

    await fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      setCountry(countryCode);
      setCountryInfo(data);
      console.log(data);
      setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]);
      // console.log("this is it:  ", mapCenter);
      setMapZoom(4);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__left">
        <div className="app__header">
          <h1>Covid-19 Tracker</h1>
          <FormControl className="app__dropdown">
            <Select
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={onCountryChange}
              value={country}
            >
              <MenuItem value="WorldWide">WorldWide</MenuItem>
              {countries.map(country => (<MenuItem value={country.value}>{country.name}</MenuItem>))}

            </Select>

          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="app__stats">
          <Infobox
            title="Cases"
            cases={countryInfo.todayCases}
            total={countryInfo.cases} />

          <Infobox
            title="Recovery"
            cases={countryInfo.todayRecovered}
            total={countryInfo.recovered} />

          <Infobox
            title="Death"
            cases={countryInfo.todayDeaths}
            total={countryInfo.deaths} />

        </div>
        <Map
          center={mapCenter}
          zoom={mapZoom}
        />
      </div>


      <Card className="app__right">
        <CardContent>
          <h3>Live case by country</h3>
          <Table countries={tableData} />
          <h3>WorldWide new cases</h3>
          <LineGraph type={type} />
        </CardContent>
      </Card>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am having a problem in the `Map` component in the `app__left` `div`. I am passing two parameters
`center` and `zoom`. Now in the function `onCountryChange` whenever a country is selected from a drop down list it should update the variable `mapCenter` and `mapZoom` so that the props in the `Map` component changes and the map is re-rendered along with the new center and zoom. However even after changing the props the `Map` component is not re-rendering. I have checked the data after `onCountryChange` everything seems OK. Somehow the component is not updating itself with the new data.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Map.css';
import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

function Map({center, zoom}) {
    return (
        <div className="map">
            <LeafletMap  center={center} zoom={zoom}>
                <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org.copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                />
            </LeafletMap>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Map
```

This is the map file.

Comment: can you show `Map`?

Comment: @Viet I have added it at the bottom.

Comment: So, in short, even after updating the `center` and `zoom` properties, updated values are not reflecting in `Map` component

Comment: And No need to use `await` if you are chaining the `fetch` and `then`

Comment: @GulamHussain yes. I guess the fetch is not affecting the map component.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of `react-leaflet`, after you set these values for the first time, they won't listen to new updates.

> Except for its children, MapContainer props are immutable: changing them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the Map instance or its container.

Source: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map

I think you'd have to imperatively update the center and zoom making use of the `useMap` hook.

They've got this example on the documentation as well:

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#hooks

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet';

function MyComponent({ center, zoom }) {
  const map = useMap()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    map.setView(center);
  }, [center]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    map.setZoom(zoom);
  }, [zoom]);
}

function Map({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
      <MyComponent center={center} zoom={zoom} />
    </MapContainer>
  )
}
```